# Как сделать подсветку каждого найденного слова в тексте, PHP?

Tags: php, css

Я совершаю поиск слов на сайте, в итоге я вывожу целую(ые) статью(ьи) с найденным словом.

```
while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){
                echo 'id ='.$row["id"].'<br />';
                echo ' title ='.$row["title"].'<br />';
                echo ' text_article ='.$row["text_article"].'<br />';

            }
```

Как мне подсветить найденные слова `$areaywords[$key]` в этой статье?

Вот мой код

```
        function search($words){
            $words = htmlspecialchars($words);
            if ($words === " ") return false;

            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "anastasiya");
            $mysqli->query("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");

            $query_search ="";
            $areaywords = explode(" ", $words);

            print_r($areaywords);
            foreach ($areaywords as $key => $value){
                    if (isset($areaywords[$key - 1]))
                    $query_search .= ' OR ';
                    $query_search .='`title` LIKE "%'.$value.'%" OR `text_article` LIKE "%'.$value.'%"';
            }
            $query = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE $query_search";
            $result_set = $mysqli->query($query);

            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { die('Ошибка соединения: <br />' . $mysqli->connect_error); } 
            //выводим количество результатов поиска
            echo 'По запросу <span style="color:blue">" '.$words.' "</span> было найдено <span style="color:blue">'.$result_set->num_rows.' строк: </span><br />';
            while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){
                echo 'id ='.$row["id"].'<br />';
                echo ' title ='.$row["title"].'<br />';
                echo ' text_article ='.$row["text_article"].'<br />';

            }
            $mysqli -> close();
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['bcearch'])){
            $words = $_POST['words'];
            $results = search($words);

    }
```

Comment: в тексте статьи каждое слово оберунть в `span` по типу `<span style="color:blue">слово</span>`. Думаю, что обычный `str_replace()` подойдет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вас взломают, так как вы не экранируете с помощью функции [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) входящие данные в своем запросе к базе.
2. У себя для выделения искомых слов использую регулярные выражения. Вот кусочек кода:

   ```
   $search = implode('|', $array_words); // $array_words - слова которые подсвечиваем, символ '*' обозначает любое количество букв/цифр
   $text = preg_replace('%(?<=[^\p{L}\p{N}])('.str_replace('*', '[\p{L}\p{N}]*', $search).')(?=[^\p{L}\p{N}])(?=[^>]*<)%ui', '<span class="shlight">$1</span>', '>'.$text.'<'); // класс shlight нужно задать в стиле
   $text = substr($text, 1, -1);
   ```

Comment: А Вы бы могли объяснить свою запись, словами?

Comment: @Anastasiya, комментарии с объяснением подписан справа от кода в первых двух строках.