# Подсветка текста, проблема

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, поиск

При поиске сделал подсветку текста таким образом

```
foreach ($words_arr as $word)  {
    $str = preg_replace("/{$word}\w*/ui", "<span class='fcolor9'>\\0</span>", $str);
}
```

где `$str` – это строка, `$word` – слово которое должно быть подсвечено, `$words_arr` – поисковый запрос.

В общем все работает если задать так
[http://apteka1.net/search?q=АСПИРИН](http://apteka1.net/search?q=%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%98%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%9D)

Но если задать так
[http://apteka1.net/search?q=АСПИРИН+c](http://apteka1.net/search?q=%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%98%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%9D+c)

Получается ерунда какая-то.

Подскажите, кто знает, где ошибка.

Comment: приведите код получение ```$words_arr``` из гет параметра + желаемый результат и текущий

Comment: $words_arr = explode(" ", $_GET['q']);

Comment: А вот так? [http://apteka1.net/search?q=АСПИР+иг](http://apteka1.net/search?q=АСПИР+иг)

Comment: хохо, подсветка с помощью регулярных выражений, в мусорку.

Comment: У вас слишком простая регулярка, которая лезет к содержимому html тегов. Тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457806/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-php я давал ответ по подсветке слов в выдаче. Смотрите как там исключение для тегов введено.

Comment: Спасибо Visman, ваше решение подошло

Answer (score 1):

Да не вижу смысла в регулярке `str_replace`

```
foreach ($words_arr as $word)  {
    $str = str_replace($word, "<span class='fcolor9'>$word</span>", $str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не касаясь само подхода к решению проблемы.

Дело в том, что в запросе [АСПИРИН+c](http://apteka1.net/search?q=%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%98%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%9D+c) у вас символ "c" латиница, которую и находит ваш же скрипт и подсвечивает вам слова – http://joxi.ru/xAeen9ef7wdVAy

У вас же цикл, соответственно после первой итерации у вас в переменной `$str` уже добавлена разметка выделения, которую заменяет на второй итерации.

PS. Не забывайте смотреть исходный HTML в браузере, а то так и будете гадать.